# Polymorphic datastructure in GraphQL with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, data-structures, polymorphism, schema, graphql

I need to create a datastructure in GraphQL (MongoDB as database) which represents the following schema:

- A **bill** can have multiple **articles**
- One **article** has a **article-group-number** and numerous attributes that 100% depend on the **article-group-number** and may vary heavily between these groups.

So one article may look like this:

```
{
article-group-number: 100,
length: 5.5
}
```

Another article may look like this:

```
{
article-group-number: 101,
width: 2
}
```

There may even be articles that have a reference to another article (but no circular structure).

I need to be able to create and maintain different validation-rules (functions) for each article-number.
How should i do this?

I was thinking about ***union*** types in GraphQL but those can only be read, not written (by "mutation") at this point in time.
Am i supposed to save those **articles** as pure JSON-data and do all validation by hand? This way i would loose the logical structure since this JSON-data field would just be some sort of a "messy data-blob" in my eyes because all logic is lost by passing through GraphQL.

Isn't there a more clean way?

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

You could take a cue from GraphQL itself -- the __Type type that is used in schemas has a "kind" field, and a lot of attributes that depend on the kind of the type.  An object type, for example, can have fields, but other kinds of types cannot.  GraphQL just puts all of the possible attributes in the __Type type and lets them take null values when they aren't applicable to the type's kind.  You could do a similar thing, and just let your articles have all possible attributes.

Or you could use a union of article types, maybe all implementing a common article interface. This is not really a problem for mutations. Since mutations are in a completely different namespace from queries, they can do whatever you want -- the type you mutate doesn't have to be the same as the type you query, and in fact usually isn't.

Both ways work.  The second way is more complicated, though, so if you're going to do that then make sure you're going to get some kind of benefit from it.

Comment: I'm not sure if i understood your first way correct. Can you provide any documentation or example? Since i haven't found any.